# Items inside header and sidebar of {shinydashboard} are not translated with {shiny.i18n}

Tags: r, shiny, internationalization, shinydashboard

#### The problem

When using `{shiny.i18n}` for live language translations in an `{shinydashboard}` app, the contents inside `dashboardHeader()` and `dashboardSidebar()` are not translated. Contents inside `dashboardBody()` are translated though.

#### Sample application

In the app below, the title of the Dashboard ("Basic dashboard") and the two menu items ("Dashboard Tab" and "Widgets Tab") are all wrapped in the `i18n$t()` function, with traditional Chinese translation (*zh*) provided in `translation_zh.csv`.

When the user changes the language from *en* to *zh*, the text of the menu items and dashboard title do not change. Meanwhile, other items inside `dashboardBody()` (e.g. "Number of observations:") are successfully translated.

How could I make the components inside `dashboardHeader()` and `dashboardSidebar()` also work with the `i18n$t()` function?

**Default view**

[image]

**After selecting *zh* as the language**

[image]

[image]

#### Sample code

The app code is merged from the [sample app of {shinydashboard}](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html) and [sample app of {shiny.i18n}](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n/blob/e11ea740994be5787066e29d4f9e17dee3772da5/examples/live_language_change/browser_app.R).

**app.R**

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny.i18n)

# File with translations
i18n <- Translator$new(translation_csvs_path = "data/")
i18n$set_translation_language("en") # here you select the default translation to display

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = i18n$t("Basic dashboard")),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(i18n$t("Dashboard Tab"), tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem(i18n$t("Widgets Tab"), tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",

              shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n),
              div(style = "float: right;",
                  selectInput('selected_language',
                              i18n$t("Change language"),
                              choices = i18n$get_languages(),
                              selected = i18n$get_key_translation())
              ),

              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

                box(
                  title = i18n$t("Controls"),
                  sliderInput("slider", i18n$t("Number of observations:"), 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2(i18n$t("Widgets tab content"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
    # This print is just for demonstration
    print(paste("Language change!", input$selected_language))
    # Here is where we update language in session
    shiny.i18n::update_lang(session, input$selected_language)
  })

  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**data/translation_zh.csv**

```
en,zh
Widgets tab content,內容
Change language,更換語言
Controls,控制台
Number of observations:,觀察數量
Basic dashboard,基本儀表版
Dashboard Tab,儀表版
Widgets Tab,部件
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original Answer

A tricky one, but after some debugging I found the reason. Without going into the technical details of the `Translator` implementation, we need to make sure that `shiny.i18n::usei18n` is called before **any** call to `i18n$t`. In your example `usei18n` is called in the **body** that is **after** all the rendering of the parts in the header and the sidebar.

The solution is to move `usei18n` to the header, which poses another small issue, as we cannot simply add it in the `...` part of it, as these items are expected to be `dropdownMenus`.

The solution is to add it to the `title` in form of a `tagList`:

```r
ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = tagList(shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n), i18n$t("Basic dashboard"))),
# ...
)
```

[image: Dashboard with translation now working in all parts of the app]

This is not the most beautiful solution, but it works. Background of this hack is that not only does `usei18n` add the resources to the HTML document, but also sets an internal flag (`private$js`) which enables live translation in the first place. Only after this flag is set a call to `i18n$t` adds the necessary `span` tags around the elements, which in turn allow for the live translation. Without this flag,  `i18n$t` simply returns the static translation.

---

### Update

The relevant part in `usei18n` is `translator$use_js()`. Thus the cleanest approach would be to add the following line to your original code:

```r
i18n$set_translation_language("en")
i18n$use_js() ### <<-- Add this
```